# Multi country page - avoid repeating content

Tags: i18n-l10n, navigation

I have a site that has several pages, and it will be available in 2 primary languages: Spanish and English.  However, in Spanish I'm creating other languanges:

- Spanish - Argentina
- Spanish - Colombia
- Spanish - Peru
- Spanish - Chile
- ...

The question is:  I don't want to repeat all the content for the Spanish speaking countries, but change 2 or 3 pages instead:  And mainly that's because I want to replace the country name in some pages.

What would be the best way to create country-specific versions of the site without duplicating all the content for each Spanish speaking country?  Thanks!

**NOTE:**  Would creating a 'language neutral' page a good idea?  And then create the English version and the changed Spanish versions when necessary?  Not yet sure what 'language neutral' is for.

Comment: If your main concern is SEO, look here: [Help Google serve the correct language or regional URL](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en). If you simply don't want to store / edit the same thing many times, then sorry, I'm a bit clueless for now.

Comment: That's good to know.  It was my second concern.  However first I need to create the content :)  Thanks @Molot!

Comment: Yea, I pretty much expected that's not what you worry about the most. That's why it wasn't an answer. Good luck with solving this puzzle :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the solution. It's not perfect, but better than having to repeat all the content 10 times :)  Here's how:

1. Use Entity translations.
2. Create a page in a language that repeats several times, eg:  Spanish - Colombia.  Translate the content in the languages that you want, it could be only the English translation for example.
3. In Entity translations module, enable language fallback.
4. If you use Pathauto, then you will have the problem that the un-translated languages won't use the friendly URL and you will be forced to use /node/nnn.  To solve this use the [Synchronize Translations Path](https://drupal.org/project/synchronize_translation_paths) module.  That way, when you edit a page, this module will enable the friendly page for all languages (either translated or not).  Remember to check its settings to enable this module for each content type!
5. For the menus, if you set a menu item language to Language Neutral, then you will be able to translate it.  If you create an item in, let's say English, you will have to create a new one in each dialect of Spanish. So you have the option to have the menu items repeated, or only once.

Some drawbacks:

- The URLs in all languages will look the same.  You won't be able to create the following:

  - `www.example.com/en/test-page`, and
  - `www.example.com/es/pagina-prueba`
- The menu items will still need to be duplicated one time per language. If there are 10 spanish-speaking countries, you will end up with 10 menu items looking the same. ==> **UPDATE:**  To avoid this, set the menu item language to Language Neutral and problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

With [domain access](https://drupal.org/project/domain) module you can share content 
and set content to show on only one specific domain name

i.e 
Argentina.Spanish.com
Colombia.Spanish.com
Peru.Spanish.com
Chile.Spanish.com